# Step by step NTLM authentication with System.Net.Http.HttpClient

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, uwp, ntlm

Im trying to implement NTLM authentication by myself.
The problem is when I try sending the type 1 message(NEGOTIATE_MESSAGE) the app throws a exception:

> An error occurred while sending the request.

And

> Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in mscorlib.ni.dll
>
> WinRT information: The login request was denied

Here is my code:

```
byte[] type1Message = new byte[40]
{
    // 'N',  'T',  'L',  'M',  'S',  'S',  'P',  '\0'
       0x4E, 0x54, 0x4C, 0x4D, 0x53, 0x53, 0x50, 0x00,
    // Type 1 message
       0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    // Flags
       0x97, 0x82, 0x08, 0xe2,
    // Supplied Domain
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    // Supplied Workstation
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    // OS Version Structure
       0x0A, 0x00, 0x39, 0x38, //0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
    // Os version uknown
       0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0f
};

var _client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:60475/");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "NTLM " + Convert.ToBase64String(type1Message));
using (var response = await _client.SendAsync(request))
{
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

In Fiddler I see that request is send and I would receive the correct answer.

Request header:

```
GET http://localhost:60475/ HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAABAAAAl4II4gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKADk4AAAADw==
Host: localhost:60475
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate TlRMTVNTUAACAAAAHgAeADgAAAAVgorixp1F6S8OipIAAAAAAAAAAJgAmABWAAAACgA5OAAAAA9EAEUAUwBLAFQATwBQAC0ATQA1ADMAUgBNAE8ASAACAB4ARABFAFMASwBUAE8AUAAtAE0ANQAzAFIATQBPAEgAAQAeAEQARQBTAEsAVABPAFAALQBNADUAMwBSAE0ATwBIAAQAHgBEAEUAUwBLAFQATwBQAC0ATQA1ADMAUgBNAE8ASAADAB4ARABFAFMASwBUAE8AUAAtAE0ANQAzAFIATQBPAEgABwAIALEnZjh/ltIBAAAAAA==
Date: Mon, 06 Mar 2017 13:40:29 GMT
Content-Length: 341
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

Have I forgot something ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is a handshake, so you need to take in the NTLM challenge, use its nonce, and then create your own nonce, then take the password hash and do the math.  This site is amazing and the java in the appendix is easy to convert to c#
http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html

Comment: Hi, yes I know. The problem is I can't get the response, because the app crashes on `using (var response = await _client.SendAsync(request))`.

Comment: I'd not send it async, as there are no other operations you need to work on while waiting. I'd recommend synchronous code.  Are you saying you see the response in fiddler, but never in your code?

Comment: `Are you saying you see the response in fiddler, but never in your code?`
Yes